# Is it possible to get forward URI from @WebFilter?

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, servlet-filters

In my JSF application I have a @WebFilter and I'd like to, when a page forward occurs, get the URI of the destination page. Is that possible?

```
@WebFilter(servletNames={"Faces Servlet"})
public class MyFilter implements Filter {   

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpRes = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        // here, can I know the URI? 

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}
}
```

Thanks